# How do display Multiple Lines in a JOptionPane with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, joptionpane

I'm trying to display 2 Arraylist in the JOptionPane. But I get the following on the dialog box

```
1,2,3,4
Swimming, Running, Cycling, Basketball
```

I would like to show the info in the dialog box like the following:

```
1 Swimming
2 Running
3 Cycling
4 Basketball
```

Please advise how do I go about? Here are my codes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class gamelist {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        ArrayList<String> sku = new ArrayList<String> ();
        sku.add("1");
        sku.add("2");
        sku.add("3");
        sku.add("4");


        ArrayList<String> games = new ArrayList<String>();
        games.add("Swimming");
        games.add("Running");
        games.add("Cycling");
        games.add("Basketball");

        for(int i = 0; i<games.size(); i++){

            String everything = sku.toString();
            String everything2 = games.toString();

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, everything +"\n"+ everything2);       
        }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this very easily.
Put those lines in a String as an output and then print that in JOptionPane. After adding your data to arraylist just do the following.

```
String output = "";
for(int i = 0; i<games.size(); i++){
    String everything = sku.get(i).toString();
    String everything2 = games.get(i).toString();

    output += everything +" "+ everything2 + "\n";       
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
```

Comment: Yes string can store that also and I have checked this for you and it works fine. You can check this code and it gives output as you mentioned above.

Comment: If you iterate through a larger array, you should use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of concatenation. It's significantly faster.